# Sequence generated by $2^k-1$ contains new prime factors

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-factorization

I was playing around with the sequence where the $k^{th}$ number is equal to $2^k-1$. It seems that all numbers except $63$ contain at least one new prime in there prime factorization. That is a prime that has not occurred in the prime factorization of any of the previous numbers in the sequence. Is there a reason why this is or can anyone find a counter example? I've been trying in mathemtica but my programming ability is sub-par.

This sequence is also generated by starting with $1$ and each term is $2k+1$ the previous term.

Note I do not care whether the term itself is prime (Mersenne primes) but that each new term contains a new prime factor.

Comment: Interesting read: A. Schinzel, On primitive prime factors of $a^n−b^n$, Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 58 (1962), 555-562

Comment: See Zsigmondy's theorem

Comment: @charMD: Would you like to make this an answer? I'd like this question to have one, and it should be yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Zsigmondy's theorem** (see [Zsigmondy's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zsigmondy%27s_theorem)), which proves what you observed : except for 63, every term of your sequence has a prime factor that does not divide the previous terms.